# How to redirect wordpress user if not logged in

Tags: wordpress

Wondering how to redirect a wordpress user to a different page if they are **not logged in**.

I can redirect with the code below if they **are logged in** but I need it to be the opposite.

If they are not logged in I need to redirect them and not vice versa.

````
```
function notallowed() {
global $post;
if ( is_page('custom-slug') && is_user_logged_in() ) { // where slug is the name or 
slug of the custom page that you want to restrict from logged in users
wp_redirect( 'https://www.customurl.com/custom-slug/', 301 ); 
exit;
}
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'notallowed' );
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `!` to negate in php. Using `if(!is_user_logged_in())` is like saying `if user is not logged in`.

So your code looks like:

```
function notallowed() {
    global $post;
    if ( is_page('custom-slug') && !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect( 'https://www.customurl.com/custom-slug/', 301 ); 
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'notallowed' );
```

This says: `If you are on page "custom-slug" and you are not logged in, you will be redirected.`